# tab contents with equal height

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a "slideshow like" content tabs with different height!
Is there anyway to make them equal height using css?
here is my code so far:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  slideIndex += n;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  slideIndex = n;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("contents");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove("active");
    slides[i].classList.remove("active-content");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active-content");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.contents {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.contents.active-content {
  display: block;
}

.content-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="contents fade">
      <h3>blah blah</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contents fade">
      <h3>blah blah</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contents fade">
      <h3>blah blah</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="text-align:center; direction: ltr">
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried flex display, but I guess it didn't work because of block and none display of its child! And using visibility didn't work either!
Also tried some other options like table/table-cell, but no luck!
any kind of information would be appreciated! THX ;)

Comment: Try to build a snippet with your code demonstrating the issue

Comment: Not sure if i understood it well but can't you jsut give the element the height of the largest text if it is known? That should be enough. But yes, a snippt will make us easier to help :) Do you need an equal height for you navigation dots?

Comment: coda slider has this functionality - https://kevinbatdorf.github.io/codaslider/.  If you are wanting to do this yourself, you would need a slide container that is the width  of all your slides put together, make that flex

Answer (score 2):

I think after putting height of your choice in `contents` class' height will be the same for all.

```
.contents {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: it will work, but I'm looking for a more responsive way to do it, without giving a specific height! just let the browser decide height!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to dynamic height of `div` as per your content. then so javascript magic can help you out.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {
    slideIndex += n;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
    slideIndex = n;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("contents");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].classList.remove("active");
      slides[i].classList.remove("active-content");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active-content");
  dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active");
}

function setheight() {
  var content = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".contents"));
  var contents = content.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.clientHeight < b.clientHeight
  });
  document.querySelector("#content-container").style.height = contents[0].clientHeight+"px";
}

setheight();
```

```css
.contents {
 visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.contents.active-content {
   visibility: visible;
}
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="content-container" id="content-container">
<div class="contents fade">
    <h3>blah blah</h3>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="contents fade">
  <h3>blah blah</h3>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="contents fade">
  <h3>blah blah</h3>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center; direction: ltr">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try defining min and max height to your contents class then the overflow to manage long texts

```
.contents {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  min-height:200px;
  max-height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: we can use fix `height` instead of using both `min-height` and `max-height`

Comment: it will work, but I'm looking for a more responsive way to do it, without giving a specific height! just let the browser decide height!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get height of all slides using js or jquery, and using loop compare it and take the highest, then set highest height to all element using loop.